# Custom button throw error on 'file` input field

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am working with `angularjs`, in my app, I would like to make a custom `file` field. for that, I have made a `span` element as a button, and i kept my `file filed` as children.

while i click on the span ( button ), i am getting an error as:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Actually i am trying to trigger the `click` event of my `file` field on click on my span.

how to solve this?

here is my HTML : ( it has multiple instants )

```
<div class="row row3">
    <div class="cell">
        <a ng-href="">Contract Details</a>
        <span class="fileUpload">
            Upload Report 
            <!-- hanlded by directive by class name  -->
            <input 
            info="contractor.Id" 
            upload="uploadFile" 
            class="uploadField upload-file-directive" 
            type="file" />
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS : ( moving away from visual )

.fileUpload .uploadField

```
border : 1px solid red;
position : absolute;
left : -200em;
```

my Directive :

//file upload handled here

```
var uploadFileDirective = function () {

    return {

        replace: false,

        restrict : 'C',

        scope : {

            info:"=",
            upload:"="

        },

        link:function ( scope, element, attrs ) {

            var button = element.parent('.fileUpload'); //selecting parent

            button.on( 'click', function () {

                $(this).children('.uploadField').click(); //triggering

            });

            element.on('change', function ( event ) { //change events

                var files = event.target.files;
                scope.upload(files, scope.info );

            });
        }

    }

}

angular.module("tcpApp")
.directive("uploadFileDirective", uploadFileDirective);
```

But I am getting above mensioned error. what is the problem here?
any one show me the correct way to make this custom `file` field.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I wrote for my app (now in production, so it's tested).

```
<div class="file-input-name">{{featuresFile.name || 'NO FILE SELECTED'}}</div>
<label class="md-primary md-raised md-button" md-ink-ripple for="file-input-fts">
    <span>Select</span>
</label>
<input id="file-input-fts" type="file" file-model="featuresFile">
<md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="upload.uploadCsvFeatures()">UPLOAD</md-button>
```

In my app I am using Angular Material, so the md-button, but you can use easily the normal html `<button>` tag.

In short words you will need to hide the actual file input and use the label as button for the search.

the css is:

```css
#file-input-fts {
    display: none;
}
```

The class prefixed with md-* are the ones from Angular Material and are used only for style purpose, you can use your own, or use that library.